# ember-cli : when to restart server

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

So I love how when I change my application in ember-cli setup everything recompiles and the page updates with livereload.  However, it seems like there are certain instances where when I change my ember app, I should need to restart my server.  In a couple of instances this helped, though I don't recall when they were.   Any clarification on when the server must be restarted would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know when you:

- change your `Brocfile.js`
- after you wake up your computer from sleep
- when you get inexplicable errors (usually related to the tmp folder not getting cleaned)

Comment: 3) when you get inexplicable errors (usually related to the tmp folder not getting cleaned)

Comment: @steveax you're absolutely right, I forgot about those as they almost never happen :)

Comment: Yes, I've had to delete my tmp folder in addition to restarting more than once

Answer (score 0):

You should restart the server after having installed an addon as well.

https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/installing-addons/